# I have to open make 'web console' window active using Ruby Watir

Tags: ruby, watir-webdriver

I am doing web automation using Ruby Watir. My steps of execution is:

1. open link
2. select my particular xml from the drop dowm menu.
3. click run button.
4. open web console window either by pressing F12 or right click mouse -> inspect element and then click Console tab.
5. select that 'Web Console' window.
6. select all from there.
7. copy all.
8. open notepad and paste it over there.

I have written code till step 4. But I an not able to get the code to select 'Web Console' window.
Please find below my code.

```
# Watir IE driver
require 'watir-webdriver'
# Required in ruby 1.8.7
require 'rubygems'

b = Watir::Browser.new :firefox
b.goto "http://engtestsite.com/kevin/dpr/beaconTester/index_html5.html"

b.button(:index => 1).click
b.select_list(:id,"selectFile").select("testCases/DPR_short_modified.xml")
b.button(:text,"Run").click

b.send_keys :f12
sleep (30)

step 5
b.send_keys [:control, "a"]
```

---

please suggest correct code for this step.

please let me know if any more details is required.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking Watir to do is not actually possible, because Watir is designed only to work in the context of a web page.

It can't also control the Browser itself. As such, it's also not going to be able to open Notepad and paste text there, either.

Comment: I do not believe this is going to work. I think they are looking for the Firefox developer toolbar, which does not get counted as a Watir window.

Comment: Ah, yes. I see what you mean. Bummer.

Comment: Edited my answer to reflect your explanation.

Comment: Hi ..... I am able to do the windows operation. I am able to open notepad, perform all the actions and close it. The only place I am stuck is switching to 'Web Console' page once I press F12.

Comment: What Watir command opens Notepad? What you are asking Watir to do is a little bit like asking a character in a television show to turn up the volume on your television set.